# Problems with load RAM on 100%

Tags: python, ram

I am conducting an experiment to load RAM at 100% on Mac OS. Stumbled upon the method described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99365

I decide to do the same. I wrote two programs which are presented below. While executing the first program, the system writes that the process takes 120 GB, but the memory usage graph is still stable. When executing the second program, almost immediately a warning pops up that the system does not have enough resources. The second program creates ten parallel processes that increase memory consumption in approximately the same way.

**First program:**

```
def load_ram(vm, timer):
    x = (vm * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 8) * (0,)

    begin_time = time.time()

    while time.time() - begin_time < timer:
        pass

    print("end")
```

[Memory occupied by the first program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeEc8.png)

**Second program:**

```
def load_ram(vm, timer):
    file_sh = open("bash_file.sh", "w")
    str_to_bash = """
        VM=%d;
        for i in {1..10};
        do
            python -c "x=($VM*1024*1024*1024*8)*(0,); import time; time.sleep(%d)" & echo "started" $i ;
        done""" % (int(vm), int(timer))
    file_sh.write(str_to_bash)
    file_sh.close()
    os.system("bash bash_file.sh")
```

[Memory occupied by the second program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0PE9.png)

[Memory occupied by the second program + system message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL0aQ.png)

Parameters: vm = 16, timer = 30.

In the first program, memory takes up are equal to about 128 gigabytes (after that, a kill pops up in the terminal and the process stops). The second takes up more than 160 gigabytes, as shown in the picture. And all these ten processes are not completed. The warning that the system is low on resources is displayed even if the memory takes up are 10 gigabytes per process (that is, 100 gigabytes in total).

According to the situation described, two questions arise:

1. Why, with the same memory consumption (120 gigabytes), in the first case, the system pretends that this process does not exist, and in the second case it immediately falls under the same load?
2. Where does the number of 120 gigabytes come from if my computer's operating system contains only 16 gigabytes?

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: Can you extend the code to an actual [mcve], i.e. add the parameters you call it with? BTW, nitpick, `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 8` bytes are 8GiB, not 8GB!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, thanks for the comment! Parameters: vm = 16, timer = 30.